# Cantor Set Closed

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I understand this question can be done by using the fact that the intersection of closed sets is closed. However, i'm assuming you could also use De Morgan's Law and show that the complement of the cantor set is open (union of open sets) hence the cantor set is closed? (Both Instances requiring induction of course)

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, intersections of closed subsets of a space are also closed. This can be derived (using De Morgan's Law) from the fact (or rather axiom of a topology) that unions of open subsets are also open. There is no need to give a special argument in the case of the Cantor set. This follows immediately from the general fact.

Answer (score 0):

one characterization of the Cantor set is that it's the set of all points in $[0,1]$ whose base-3 expansion does not contain any $1$'s. You can use this fact to prove that the Cantor set is closed by showing that all limit points do not contain any $1$'s in their base-3 expansion. Of course, it's trivial that the complement is open so you can go that route too.